# How to use generic method to replace duplicated properties?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

Currently my code has the following properties:

```
  Private _queueRetriever As Services.IQueueRetriever
  Public ReadOnly Property QueueRetriever As Services.IQueueRetriever
     Get
        If _queueRetriever Is Nothing Then
           RemotingSetup.RegisterHttpBinaryChannel()
           _queueRetriever = RemotingFactory.CreateProxy(Of Services.IQueueRetriever)(Options.DevLocal)
        End If

        Return _queueRetriever
     End Get
  End Property

  Private _queueCountRetriever As Services.IQueueCounter
  Public ReadOnly Property QueueCounter As Services.IQueueCounter
     Get
        If _queueCountRetriever Is Nothing Then
           RemotingSetup.RegisterHttpBinaryChannel()
           _queueCountRetriever = RemotingFactory.CreateProxy(Of Services.IQueueCounter)(Options.DevLocal)
        End If

        Return _queueCountRetriever
     End Get
  End Property
```

As you can see, the code is essentially the same for both properties. Only the types are different. I'm not very experienced in generic methods, but I feel like I should be able to make this code more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) using generics. Can it be done or is this not a job for generic methods?

**EDIT**

Building on Marc's answer, I came up with the following:

```
  Protected Services As New Dictionary(Of Type, Object)

  Protected Function CreateService(Of T)() As T
     If Not Services.ContainsKey(GetType(T)) Then

        RemotingSetup.RegisterHttpBinaryChannel()
        Services.Add(GetType(T), RemotingFactory.CreateProxy(Of T)(Options.DevLocal))

     End If

     Return DirectCast(Services(GetType(T)), T)
  End Function
```

Which, of course, can be used like so:

```
Me.CreateService(Of IService).Foo()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do (and apologies for switching into C#, but my VB skills lack the subtlety here - I'm sure it works fine in VB too though)

```
private T GetProxy<T>(ref T field) where T : class {
    if(field == null) {
        RemotingSetup.RegisterHttpBinaryChannel();
        field = RemotingFactory.CreateProxy<T>(Options.DevLocal);
    }
    return field;
}
```

with:

```
private Services.IQueueCounter queueCounter;
public Services.IQueueCounter QueueCounter {
    get { return GetProxy(ref queueCounter); }
}
private Services.IQueueRetriever queueRetriever;
public Services.IQueueRetriever QueueRetriever {
    get { return GetProxy(ref queueRetriever); }
}
```

Comment: There's a reason he has 240k+ rep. I thought about the helper method, didn't think to use the ref keyword to cover the initializing of the field in the method as well. I would upvote 5 times if I could. My suggestions pales in the face of this.

Comment: Cool! Is it not possible to replace the properties completely with a method that would perhaps maintain a dictionary of instantiated services?

Comment: @TaylorOtwell if you wanted, probably

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Thanks! You're example got me close enough I was able to write just a method that maintains a Dictionary of services.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a private generic method that gives you back the appropriate channel, but in this case you basically would replace 2 lines of code with 1 line of code and the a two line method call. It may not be worth the effort, other than if you add a third type of channel you would save yourself the danger of in the third case forgetting the `RemotingSetup.RegisterHttpBinaryChannel` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create generic properties in .Net

What you could do, is create a generic method to be called in the Get:

```
  Private _queueCountRetriever As Services.IQueueCounter
  Public ReadOnly Property QueueCounter As Services.IQueueCounter
     Get
        Return MyGet(Of QueueCounter ,IQueueCounter )(_queueCountRetriever)
     End Get
  End Property

  Private Function MyGet(Of T As IT, IT)(ByRef propertyVar As T ) As IT
       If propertyVar Is Nothing Then
           RemotingSetup.RegisterHttpBinaryChannel()
           propertyVar = RemotingFactory.CreateProxy(Of IT)(Options.DevLocal)
        End If
  End Function
```